# Draw an arc in clockwise direction in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cgcontext

How to draw an arc ring with clockwise direction starting from zero.I need the arc to start from 0 and arc ending point can vary. as shown in the image[image: Circular progress]

Comment: Did you bother looking in the documentation or do any research? Maybe search for the words  "cgcontext" and "arc"? You should be able to find `CGContextAddArc()`

Comment: @rdurand That question is only a dupe if the OP wants to animate the circle

Comment: "How to draw an arc ring with clockwise direction starting from zero" sounds a lot like that to me..

Comment: @rdurand Yeah, you are probably correct. Otherwise the OP wouldn't have been so specific about the direction and the start angle.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist i wanted to know how to start the circle from 0,thanks for the negative support ,well i have found out what to do     CGContextAddArc(ctx, self.frame.size.width/2  , self.frame.size.height/2, radius , -M_PI, ToRad(self.angle), 0);

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist It was the -M_PI that i needed

Comment: @Nassif your question included very little detail. You didn't include any code that showed what you were working with, so how can we know where to start to help you? But since you found an answer, you should post it below and accept it as the answer. It will add to your reputation points.

Comment: @rdurand It was not the animation i needed.Please do check out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What i wanted was to start an arc from the left side.(-180) and i did in this way

[image: circular]

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

[super drawRect:rect];

CGRect customRect = rect;
customRect.origin.x = 5;
customRect.origin.y = 6;
customRect.size.width = rect.size.width -10;
customRect.size.height = rect.size.height - 12;


radius = customRect.size.width/2 - ((customRect.size.width/2)*0.3);


CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect (ctx, customRect);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(ctx, customRect);
CGContextFillPath(ctx);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextAddArc(ctx, self.frame.size.width/2  , self.frame.size.height/2, radius , -M_PI, ToRad(self.angle), 0);

CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, customRect.size.width/2 - (radius + 2));
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathStroke);
}
```